# jquery hide closest button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery and I'm stuck on this.

I am trying to hide `button` when input value is 200, but there are other inputs too. This question has been asked earlier but I couldn't figure it out in my case.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var test = $('.input-text').val();
    if (test = 200) {
      $('button').hide();
    }
  }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="200">
  <button>
    Hide me
  </button>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="300">
  <button>
    Hide me
  </button>
</div>

<div class="third">
  <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="400">
  <button>
    Hide me
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) What div do you want to hide and when what? Do you want to hide the div "first", "second" or "third" when the button is pressed?

Comment: sorry , i wrote div ,  i am trying to hide button when input value is 200 , but all buttons gets hidden .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in your logic.

- `setTimeout` is unnecessary
- `val()` returns a string which you're comparing to an int, which will give some unreliable outcomes.
- there are multiple input elements, so you need to evaluate their values individually.
- you're hiding all `button` elements, you need to traverse the DOM to find the `button` related to each `input`

With that said, this should work for you:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $('.input-text').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) == 200) {
      $(this).next('button').hide();
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
  <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="200">
  <button>
    Hide me
  </button>
</div>

<div class="second">
  <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="300">
  <button>
    Hide me
  </button>
</div>

<div class="third">
  <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="400">
  <button>
    Hide me
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Try like following.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.input-text').each(function() {
            if (this.value == 200) {
                $(this).next('button').hide();
            }
        });
    }, 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first">
    <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="200">
    <button>
        Hide me
    </button>
</div>

<div class="second">
    <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="300">
    <button>
        Hide me
    </button>
</div>

<div class="third">
    <input class="input-text qty text" type="number" readonly="" value="400">
    <button>
        Hide me
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues.

`var test = $('.input-text').val();` Will only ever retrieve the `value` of the first `.input-text`

`if (test = 200)` is assigning `test = 200` rather than evaluating (`==`).

`$('button').hide();` will hide every button on the page.

You could filter the buttons, and return the ones whose previous input value is 200, and then hide them:

```
$('.input-text + button').filter( function() {
  return $(this).prev().val() == 200;
}).hide();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frk6gh0b/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery.nearest

```
$('#id').closest(".classname");
```

Comment: `closest()` looks for parent elements; the button is a sibling of the input

Answer (score 0):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       $('.input-text').each(function(){
       var test = $(this).val();
       if(test == 200) {
          $('.input-text').next("button").hide();
       }
});

    },10);
});
```

You need to check sibling of all `.input-text` where condition is met with `next()`.

`next()` selects the first sibling of element you selected depending on condition (`if` `.val == 200`). And then it makes that sibling gone.

Also, you should test all `.input-text` elements with `each()`.